# Scaling of frame creates a little point

Tags: align, framed, scale

I am trying to figure out why latex puts a little point after at the beginning of align environment I am scaling to fit the pagewidth.

As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

After subtracting of $\left( \theta_{m+1,i } - \theta^*_{,i} \right)^2$ and multiplying with $\dfrac{(1-\beta_1^m) \sqrt{\hat{v}_{m,i}}}{2 \gamma_m (1-\beta_{1,m})}$ we arrive at:
\begin{frame} 
\footnotesize 
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt} % default: 5pt 
\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu 
\begin{align*} 
\Leftrightarrow && 0 & = \dfrac{(1-\beta_1^m) \sqrt{\hat{v}_{m,i}}}{2 \gamma_m (1-\beta_{1,m})} \left( \left( \theta_{m,i } - \theta^*_{,i} \right)^2 - \left( \theta_{m+1,i } - \theta^*_{,i} \right)^2 \right) - \Phi_{m,i}  \left( \theta_{m,i } - \theta^*_{,i} \right)  \\ &&&  - \dfrac{\beta_{1,m}}{1-\beta_{1,m}} \kappa_{m-1,i}  \left( \theta_{m,i } - \theta^*_{,i} \right) + \dfrac{(1-\beta_1^m) \sqrt{\hat{v}_{m,i}}\gamma_m}{2  (1-\beta_{1,m})}  \left( \dfrac{\hat{\kappa}_{m,i}}{\sqrt{\hat{v}_{m,i}}}  \right)^2
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Where does that point come from and how do I remove it?
Thanks!

Now the results yields this:
[image: f]

Answer (score 4):

`\frame` is a standard LaTeX command, a version of `\fbox`  so

```
\begin{frame}
```

is essentially `\frame{}` so like `\fbox{}` and makes a small square.

perhaps you intended

```
\begin{framed}
```

from the `framed`  package.

Comment: But framed gives me essentially framebox around the intended area. This does not really help. Is there a way to hide the framed box? Furthermore, framed squeezes everything to very tiny, since the framed environment has quite a big margin. So everything gets literally really small.

Comment: @Christian.gruener ????? well what do you want the environment to do? If you don't want a frame around the alignment just remove `\begin{frame(d)}`  `\end{frame(d)}`

Comment: @Christian.gruener I do not understand your references to things becoming small (or your references to scaling in the question) there is no scaling in this file and `framed` has no effect at all on font size.

Comment: oh boy... -.-.. As seen in the example my equations are really long. So what I want to do is squeeze the fractions of spaces and such together so that the align environment fits into my \textwidth. Therefore, I found another thread saying I should use frame. If you have a better idea of how to solve this issue please go ahead :)

Comment: I think this question is answered, the small dot is `\frame{}` that is an empty framed box. If you want to ask about linebreaking in math ask a new question but you are already `\footnotesize` no point making the fonts smaller if you want people to read it, just make the lines shorter by adding more `\\ ` somewhere suitable. But As seen in this example your equations are not really long, they easily fit within the text width with no overfull boxes. @Christian.gruener

Comment: Congratulations you solved the point issue as you mentioned. Please stop being passive aggressive - You could solve the issue by telling me how I am able to apply `\medmuskip = 1mu` in just the align environment and everyone is happy

Comment: sorry you found my comments aggressive I honestly just did not (and do not) understand most of your earlier comments about sizes and scaling as they do not appear to apply to the document posted. if you want to set medmuskip locally just set it inside any group `{\medmuskip = 1mu... }`  or an environment, I don't believe you asked about anything related to that previously so I'm not sure why you think me not mentioning that is passive aggressive? @Christian.gruener

Comment: @Christian.gruener also you should use `\!` before the `^2` after the big brackets, it will look nicer and save more space